# C# EPPLUS can't get cell value

Tags: c#, .net, epplus

I have Cell "A1" with the value of 1.00, set by a formula

I want to save this value to a variable.

I tried:

```
ws.Cells["A1"].Value
ws.Cells["A1"].Text
ws.Cells["A1"].GetValue<double>
ws.Cells["A1"].Value.ToString()
```

None of these work as I either get an error or I don't get my number at all (console.writeline outputs a blank).

I tried searching online and I get what I tried above. I know I'm referencing the cell correctly because I can actually set the value just fine.

So how do I actually get my value of 1.00 and save it in a double variable?

EDIT: my code, where the worksheet in the filePath has "A1" value of 1.00

```
using (var pck = new ExcelPackage(filePath))
{
   var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets[1];

   var test1 = ws.Cells["A1"].Value;
   var test2 = ws.Cells["A1"].Text;
   var test3 = ws.Cells["A1"].GetValue<double>();

   Console.WriteLine(test1);
   Console.WriteLine(test2);
   Console.WriteLine(test3);
 }
```

output is:

```
[blank]
[blank]
0
```

EDIT2: The value of 1.00 is from a formula

Comment: Just checking - your code does have something like Double myVar = ws.cells["A1"].Value ?

Comment: Can you put full line of your code to get the cell value?.

Comment: @andrew When I do that I get an error saying you can't convert type object to double. I do have var ws.cells["A1"].Value instead

Comment: I have used code like.. decimal myDec = (decimal)ws.Cells["A1"].Value successfully; you could try that - casting to Double instead. Also in your edit above, you're assigning ws to the worksheet, but then using comparisonWS which has not been assigned ?

Comment: I'll try it and update you. Sorry for the comparisonWS, I was copy pasting and i actually meant to replace it with ws to be more general

Comment: I notice you are using `var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets[1];`.  Unlike the Excel COM object model, indexers start at 0, so this will select the *second* worksheet in your workbook.  Is this what you want?

Comment: @Joe - are you sure? Because I can set and change the value of the cell just fine.

Comment: New update...I think it matters that the cell value of 1.00 comes from a formula. I tried it when the value is hard set and it works fine. But when it comes from a formula it stops working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for the hassle. By doing ws.Cell["A1"].Calculate() I can get the value. Stupid me for omitting that fact

Comment: I am still getting the error even after I call Calculate(). Please help !!

Answer (score 8):

Get the cell value using the row and column indices. This value is in string.
Convert the string value to double.

Try this:

```
var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets[1];

//var test1 = ws.Cells[rowIndex, columnIndex].Value;
//For cell A1 - rowIndex is 1, columnIndex is 1
var test1 = ws.Cells[1, 1].Value;
double dValue = Convert.ToDouble(test1);
```

Comment: Add some more explanation to your answer. It's being flagged as a low quality because it's short.